# Declaring a pointer type in the parameter of a function to modify a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I know that in order for a function to write to a parameter, we need to pass a pointer to that parameter. That's also the case if we want to modify a linked list. The thing that I struggle to understand, is that why we need to declare a pointer type P* instead of declaring just the normal type in order to modify the linked list?

What are the main differences between the two examples?

```
int function(struct list_t** list){

}
int function(struct list_t* list){

}
```

I can say that in both the examples, I'm passing the pointer to the parameter, which technically allows me to edit the linked list.

Comment: "... both the examples, I'm passing the pointer to the parameter" --> This is not shown. To show what is being passed, post the calling code.  Functions definitions here show what is being received.  In both cases, a pointer is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `struct list_t* list` then `list` is a pointer to a `list_t`.

With `struct list_t** list` then `list` is a pointer *to a pointer* to a `list_t`.

If you have e.g.

```
list_t* my_list;
```

then `my_list` is a pointer to a `list_t`. If you then use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to `my_list` (as in `&my_list`) then you get a pointer to a pointer to a `list_t`, which is `list_t**`.

---

The use of pointers to pointers is to emulate pass-by-reference in C, which only have pass-by-value. As you say, if you have a pointer to a pointer, then you can dereference it and make it point somewhere else. With a plain pointer, it's passed by value and the value is copied into the argument variable. Modifying a copy will not modify the original.